# Implementing SSL/TLS/AUTO

Tags: ssl, openssl

I'm adding TLS/SSL option to my email client using openssl. 3 options can be selected: AUTO, TLS, SSL (like Outlook Express's "encrypted connection option").

I'm curious that when 'AUTO' option selected, how it should work?
How can I select the best option for a specific mail server?
If I have to try the options one by one by priority (maybe TLS -> SSL -> none), how can I check the attempt fails?

Any advice will be welcomed.

Answer (score 0):

First, make the determination based on the port number.  The secure e-mail ports are `993` for IMAP and `995` for POP3.  So if you're connecting to either of these ports, use TLS or SSL to connect.

If the port number is standard IMAP `143` or POP3 `110`, then you need to do an unsecure connection and query the capabilities of the mail server.  You initiate a secure connection with the [STARTTLS](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2595.txt) command.

During TLS negotiation, you tell the server what you're capable of (TLSv1 and SSLv3 for example) and the server picks which one to use.

If you have an AUTO option, you should show a "lock" icon or some other indicator in the user interface so that the user knows whether or not the connection is encrypted.  Otherwise they'd have no idea which connection method you used.

You may want to look at [this article](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Secure_connections_-_Thunderbird) on how Thunderbird does it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. 
I did like this:
TCP connect to the server, and if it sends HELLO reply immediately, I think it's using TLS. If server don't reply in timeout, it's using SSL.
Is there no problem to this solution? I don't like this because when I use auto option, I have to wait during timeout if server is using SSL.
I'm curious there is any openssl API, I searched the mailing list but I couldn't find.